# Ad authentication at ALB level

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, meteor, active-directory

I have a chat application (meteor on node js server over Linux) that is hosted in load-balanced Ec2 instances though an application load balancer ALB. The application works fine without any issues.

I want to implement AWS AD authentication for the same. Means, when I invoke ALB URL in the browser, first it should go to Microsoft login page, then it needs to be authenticated, then only it should be redirected to the application.

How to do this configuration? is the configuration need to be done in the AWS console ONLY? or anything needs to do in the code as well?

Comment: Can you narrow down this question to a specific situation of code? Is this question Meteor-specific or would it apply to any other node app?

Comment: this is meteor specific

Comment: how? As far as I can see this is AWS specific and would apply to any nodejs app.

Comment: There are two ways to do it, one is in AWS console only, other in the meteor side, I like to know both sides.

Comment: you can do it in the console itself but with infrastructure as code you can reuse the configurations.